# ID a marine creature found on a beach on the US east Coast

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

While walking on a marshy beach, I found this creature. It has no eyes, no feet, no fin, no gills. The only thing I know is that the skin lightly contracts. I found at least three of these. It is basically carried around by water.

[image: Photo of the strange creature]

Found this on a Maryland beach, roughly 150 miles east of Washington D.C.

Comment: Where was this found?

Comment: edited description to add this information.

Comment: nice and clear photos

Answer (score 1):

It's positively a sea anemone. It retracts the tentacles when disturbed and become quite rigid. It's hard to identify it in this condition, leave it for a whlie in a jar with sea water and you'll see.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, it could be a sponge (but I don't think sponges have a contractile skin), a [tunicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunicate) or a [sea cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_cucumber).

I would favour the last option.

- The following questions might help further identification: How many holes can you spot?
- If there are 2, where are they placed with respect to one another?

I hope someone can propose something more precise.

#### Edit:

As noted in the comments, it could also be a [sea anemone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_anemone). In my experience, these have a quite soft body. In that case, it should have only one opening, and the opening should let tentacles out when the animal is left quiet in the proper environment.

Comment: Paranthus rapiformis has a similar form.